# al usar el evento click , captura mas de 1 click

Tags: javascript

al momento de usar el evento click , me captura mas de un click y no se porque , yo solo hago un click y deberia capturarme solo 1 click. lo que quiero hacer en que cuando llegue a 6 click , desaparesca  un div .

```
var arrowsDerecha = document.querySelector('.arrows-derecha');

let contadorDerecha = 0;

function verClick (){    

   arrowsDerecha.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

      if (contadorDerecha == 6){
         arrowsDerecha.style.opacity = "0";
         console.log("SE AH DESACTIVADO LA OPACIDAD LLEGASTE A 6");

      }else{

         contadorDerecha ++;
   
         console.log("Has dado "+ contadorDerecha + "Click");
         

      }
   });

   return contadorDerecha
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el bloque de HTML y los estilos para tener un ejemplo mínimo con el que poder hacer pruebas?

Comment: Algo me dice que tienes en tu html un `onclick = "verClick()"` lo cual es obvio la causa de tus problemas ya que estás suscribiéndote al evento nuevamente cada vez que llamas a la función. Si estás llamando a la función desde el html, no necesitas el addEventListener.

Comment: eh revisado y no tengo , todas las funciones lo tengo en la hoja de estilo de js

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .target {
            border        : 1px solid red;
            border-radius : 5px;
            height        : 50px;
            margin        : auto;
            width         : 90%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <button type="button">Clic aquí</button>
        <p>Total clicks: <strong id="total_clicks">0</strong></p>
        <div class="target" id="target"></div>
    </main>

    <script>
        handleButtonClicks();

        function handleButtonClicks() // void
        {
            let counter = 0;
            const button = document.querySelector('button');
            const target = document.querySelector('#target');
            const counterInfo = document.querySelector('#total_clicks');

            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                counter++;
                counterInfo.textContent = counter;

                if (counter === 6) {
                    button.disabled = true;
                    target.style.display = 'none';
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: funciona correcto , entonces en donde falle yo ? hice la misma logica pero a mi cuando doy click, en la consola me sale que eh ejectuado varios click y solo hice un click

Comment: habia usado 2 eventos de listener diferentes contenido pero con el mismo evento click, con el mismo div , y creo que eso causo el doble click